# Не работает множественный поиск preg_match_all

Tags: php, регулярные-выражения

```
preg_match_all('/src=\"data\:image\/(jpeg|png);base64\,(.+?)\">/iU', $content, $images);
```

Находит только одно изображение из контента, остальные игнорирует.
Гдето ошибка в регулярке.

Comment: А если так - `'~src="data:image/(?:jpeg|png);base64,([^"]*)">~i'`?

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew работает отлично!

Comment: В общем, удалите флаг `U`.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew напишите в ответе, я одобрю.

Comment: Да это всё одно и то же, "используйте ленивый квантификатор". После 1000 раз надоедает повторять.